# Function only called once on window resize

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting this to work:

http://codepen.io/lukejacksonn/pen/PwmwWV

The code works perfectly when the window is being resized. When there is enough space, 1 item is being put back in the menu.

***But*** when you go from a narrow screen and maximize the browser (without dragging it to make it bigger) the code only puts 1 item back, even though there should be enough space for multiple items or even all of them. (Try it out in the link above: make it narrow and then maximize the browser, only one item is put back)

Here is the part that takes the first item from the `.hidden-links` and puts it back to `.visible-links`.

```
if(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1]) {

  // Move the item to the visible list
  $hlinks.children().first().appendTo($vlinks);
  breaks.pop();
}
```

The function is being called only once, so it makes sense only 1 item is put back when you maximize the browser. After all you only resize the window once.

How to make it so that all elements (as many that can fit) are put back when maximizing the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// change to while loop
while(availableSpace > breaks[breaks.length-1]) {

  // Move the item to the visible list
  $hlinks.children().first().appendTo($vlinks);
  breaks.pop();
}
```